# Element Array Access within a Deferred Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, arrays, deferred

How would I access the values of 'timestamp' and 'usage' in the following example,

```
function executeReadingsQuery(query, postQueryProcessing) {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    var processing = function(tx, results) {
        var result = [];
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result.push({
                "timestamp" : moment(results.rows.item(i).timeStamp),
                "usage" : results.rows.item(i).usage
            });

        }
        if (postQueryProcessing) {
            result = postQueryProcessing(result);
        }
        d.resolve(result);
    }; 

    executeQuery(query, processing);
    return d;
}
```

A function that builds a query string will subsequently call the above function,

```
function getReadingsInternal(noOfReadings, postQueryProcessing) {
    var query = "SELECT * from usage ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit " + noOfReadings.toString();
    return executeReadingsQuery(query, postQueryProcessing);
}
```

And then there is another function that exposes the entire functionality globally,

```
getReadings : function(noOfReadings) {
        return getReadingsInternal(noOfReadings);
    }
```

The original function (the first one listed) is within a Variable called WNDatabase
So I can access the function with a call that looks like this

```
WNDatabase.getReadings(30)
```

But I would like to be able to also globally access the values of timestamp and usage which populate the result[] array of the deferred object.
It seems that it is not possible to do something like this

```
  $.when(WNDatabase.getReadings(30)).done(function() {

        for(var i=0; i<7; i++){

        console.log(this[i].usage);
        }

    });
```

So what would one do in this event?

Comment: try `done(function(results) {` and use that instead of `this`.

Comment: could u please elaborate on your suggested usage of that. when i try console.log(that[i].usage) it of course complains that "that" is not a function?

Comment: The results from a promise are passed to the `done` function as a parameter, not as `this`. by `that` I meant the `results` parameter. so would be `done(function(results) {` and `console.log(results[i].usage)`

Comment: levi 'that' totally solved the issue. thanks a million!